# The requested URL was not found on this server after SSL. Apache. WordPress. Self host

Tags: wordpress, ssl, https, http-status-code-404

A few days ago I have installed SSL certificate and move to https. After this no one page (except homepage) was not abble to open. Each time I get an error `The requested URL was not found on this server. Apache/2.4.18.` 
After I pick in `Settings -> Permalincs -> General -> Simple` all started to work. But now I cant change permalinks from simple to something else because of error. Using plugin Really Simple SSL.

## `.htaccess` (644 permission but I've tryed 777)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

================================

## apache2.conf

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

===============

```
mod_rewrite activated
/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
```

=========================

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    <Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    . . .
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. Apatch do not give permission to redirect from `.htacces` by default. So I have changed `/etc/apatche2/sites-avelable/domain_name.conf`

```
<Directory /var/www/mydomain>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
```

And it helped. 
Also you can try change this permission in `/etc/apatche2/sites-avelable/000-default.conf`
and do not forget to turn on `sudo a2enmod rewrite` and restart `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart`.
Also check `.htaccess` permission (666 or 777). After work change back to 644.
Last one -> check `apache2.conf` and set `AllowOverride All` on `<Directory /var/www/mydomain>`

Comment: Hi, having trouble finding `/etc/apatche2/sites-avelable/domain_name.conf`

Any chance you could give the path to `/etc` please?